# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when trying to run jar

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, jar, build.gradle

I have a spring boot project using gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.1.4.Final'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.5.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'base-name'
    version = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.application.Application'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

I build using
`./gradlew clean jar`
Then try to run using
`java -jar <jar-name>.jar`

However I get an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at some.application.Application.main(Application.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I am so confused as to why I can run it in IDE but not as a jar. Also I found out that my jar doesn't contain any libraries at all.

EDIT:

This is my `Application.class`

package some.application;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would compare the paths that IDE is using and the contents of the jar

Comment: do you have the springboot entry class in your code ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis edited question showing my `Application.java`. Is that what you meant by spring boot entry class?

Comment: @efekctive I just checked my jar, and apparently it does not contain any spring boot jars at all whatsoever. This explains then why it can't run anything. Do you know how I shove spring boot jars into my jar?

Comment: what happens when you do gradle install ? It doesnt bring in the dependencies?

Comment: @EduardoDennis My IDE sees all the dependencies and gradle does bring them in. But when I do jar, the generated jar contains absolutely no other jars, just my code.

Comment: I think you need to remove the WAR plugin, if you want an executable jar. Also try the bootRepackage plugin. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration

Comment: I think you need to create a fat jar but I have not done with gradle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because your dependencies are not included into the end jar file.

Take a look on the examples [here](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) or [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571/5).

Or alternatively use `./gradlew clean build` that should automatically pack the app correctly. Take a look on [the official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

Comment: beautiful. Adding `from {
  (configurations.runtime).collect {
   it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
  }
 }` worked like a charm for me :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a task called `fatJar` in `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'base-name'
    version = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.github:'
        )
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest.from jar.manifest
//    classifier = 'all'
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    with jar
}

artifacts {
    archives fatJar
}
```

2. Run `gradle fatJar` or `./gradlew fatJar` to generate a `jar` file with all dependencies, which can run independently but may be pretty large in size (that's why it's called a fat  jar).

Answer (score 0):

From the official Spring-Boot-Site - [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies)

Try creating a jar with: `gradle clean bootJar`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide more information on how this helps OP's problem? Answers should preferably be self contained, meaning all necessary information to understand the answer should be written in the answer and not in external links because links can break over time. (Feel free to quote a source and link to it, but please put the important information here)

Answer (score -1):

I tried out Sasha Shpota answer and that was my problem too... finally after hours of searching that helped me thanks a lot <3 added this to my grade.build:

```
jar {
   from {
           configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : 
  zipTree(it) }
          }
}
```

Better look at Sasha Shpotas answer